# Will CONSISTENCY TWO be affected by low remote DC latency if all local replicas are up?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Scenario: we have up in aws a DSE 5.0 cluster cluster with 2 DCs, and a keyspace with 3 replicas in Australia and 3 replicas in US West coast. App talks to DSE via the dse java driver.

For our users in Sydney, If we use LOCAL_QUORUM, response times as measured in the client are under 90ms. This is good, but if 2 replicas are too slow (happened during a nasty repair caused by the analytics cluster) we are down.

If we use QUORUM, we can lose 2 nodes locally without going down, but our response times are over 450ms at all times because every read needs at least one answer from the remote DC.

My question is: will using CL TWO (which is enough for our case) suffer the same latency cost of QUORUM if all our 3 local replicas are healthy and behaving?

Our end goal is having low latency while still being automatically fail over and eat the latency cost if local fails.

If it makes any difference, we are using DCAwareRoundRobin in the driver.

Comment: your willing to violate strong consistencies if you go with CL.TWO so might as well do CL.LOCAL_ONE and get best of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DCAwareRoundRobin policy provides round-robin queries over the node of
>   the local data center. It also includes in the query plans returned a
>   configurable number of hosts in the remote data centers, but those are
>   always tried after the local nodes. In other words, this policy
>   **guarantees that no host in a remote data center will be queried unless
>   no host in the local data center can be reached.**

CONSISTENCY TWO returns the most recent data from two of the closest replicas.

[CONSISTENCY In Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html)

Answer (score 1):

To obtain minimal latency in Scylla/Cassandra over a multi-dc implementation, you'd need to use the local aspect of the driver.
The challenge with the CL=Two is that it provides the closest response from the nearest replicas based on your snitch configuration.
To my understanding, it means that the coordinator node request is sent to all replicas without the locality aspect. It means you'd be charged for the egress traffic from both sides of the pond. once for the request and once for the actual data traffic coming from all replicas.